# Daphne keeps exiting without any error under supervisor

Tags: supervisord, django-channels

I am running daphne under supervisord following the official docs.It keeps failing for some reason wihout any clear error
Below is the supervisor log

```
2021-07-18 15:35:01,110 INFO Creating socket tcp://localhost:8000
2021-07-18 15:35:01,112 INFO spawned: 'asgi0' with pid 15075
2021-07-18 15:35:01,116 INFO exited: asgi0 (exit status 0; not expected)
2021-07-18 15:35:01,116 INFO Closing socket tcp://localhost:8000
2021-07-18 15:35:04,128 INFO Creating socket tcp://localhost:8000
2021-07-18 15:35:04,130 INFO spawned: 'asgi0' with pid 15079
2021-07-18 15:35:04,134 INFO exited: asgi0 (exit status 0; not expected)
2021-07-18 15:35:04,134 INFO Closing socket tcp://localhost:8000
2021-07-18 15:35:05,136 INFO gave up: asgi0 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Here's the supervisor config file

```
[fcgi-program:asgi]
# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://localhost:8000
# environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.dev_settings
# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/jaga/C42
# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
# Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
command=bash -c 'source /etc/environment' && daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 10 --access-log - --proxy-headers mysite.asgi:application

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=1

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/var/log/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Same happened when there were 4 processes.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you manage to find the answer (since 5 months have passed)?

Comment: @miloslu No.. I ended up using systemd

Answer (score 0):

I applyed this docs: [django channels to production](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#example-setups) and it's work.

Notice that you must create the `/run/daphne` directory then apply the good permission.

```
mkdir -p /run/daphne && chown www-data:www-data
```

For django my setup is:

```ini
[supervisord]

user=root
nodaemon=true

logfile=/dev/stdout
logfile_maxbytes=0

environment=
    VIRTUAL_ENV=/srv/env \
    PATH="/srv/env/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"

[fcgi-program:application]

user=www-data
group=www-data
directory=/var/www/application

socket=tcp://0.0.0.0:5000
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

command=daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers main.asgi:application

stdout_logfile=/var/log/application_stdout.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

As extra the `asgi.py`

```py
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')
django.setup()

'''
Django is setuped.
Keep rows above, order is important.

All the line bellow works as standard project. 
'''

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

import main.routing as main_routing

print("Use ASGI server")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(
                URLRouter(
                    main_routing.websocket_urlpatterns
                )
            )
        ),
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what here will fix the problem exactly?

Comment: As he sayed, he don't know the cause of the error; that is why I gave a setup that works. To feed back the config: storing environnement into /etc folder is absolutly not a good pratice, a better practice is storing in /var or /srv folder. Also the user who should run the command is not specified then sourcing environnement in sub bash is not a good; notice this is the reason of no error message, because bash end the execution with exit success.